# Multiple table rows as single component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

What would be a way to have multiple table rows in a single Angular component ?
I would like to display two rows per item of a given list, and have it in an HTML table.

I tried using ng-template with a component as attribute to avoid having a component tag breaking the table flow, but the input won't work in that case. Ideally I'm looking for a way to remove the component tag from the dom...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>City</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container app-located-person
                  *ngFor="let person of persons"
                  [person]="person">
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**App located person**

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ person.city }}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="details">
  <td>Last connection</td>
  <td>{{ person.lastConnection }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are trying to remove the component tag from the DOM? You can simply use <app-located-person> and it should work, if you want to hide/remove it, just pass an @Input variable that controls its visibility

Comment: Tables only allows table related tags (td, tr, th...). A component tag would break the expected table behavior for the tr tags inside it

Comment: You can't use `<ng-container app-located-person>` like this. `app-located-person` would be a directive in that case. And correct me if I'm wrong but you can't bind a template to a directive. :)
Why don't you inject the whole table in your subcomponent?

Comment: @MattWalterspieler I have bound a directive's html to a div in order to preserve framework structure before.  Obviously a div is different than an ng-container.  I define it as a component but the selector was set to: `[app-located-person]` so it applied it to wherever that specific attribute was used.

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's the purpose of the question ;) I simplified the example but I would actually like the row component to make some calls for the inner data to display, but only when if it's expanded

Answer (score 4):

I finally made it not to break the table dom flow by using `display: table-row-group;` on the component node :)

Comment: FYI, in Angular Material, for their table component they used flex instead of the "classical" HTML table. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table.scss

Might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you include the `tr`'s inside the `ng-container` tag?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>City</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container 
     *ngFor="let person of persons"
     [person]="person">
       <tr>
         <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ person.city }}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr *ngIf="details">
         <td>Last connection</td>
         <td>{{ person.lastConnection }}</td>
       </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to use a component:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>City</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container 
     *ngFor="let person of persons">
       <app-located-person [person]="person"></app-located-person>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>City</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let person of persons">
      <tr>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.city}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="person.lastConnection">
        <td>Last connection</td>
        <td>{{person.lastConnection}}</td>
      </tr>      
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Stackblitz: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7j77qu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)